# Passing a value from UIViewController to UIView

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have the following UIViewController class:

FILE: **ResultsDataViewController.h**

```
@interface ResultsDataViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* name;
@end
```

FILE : **ResultsDataViewController.m**

```
#import "ResultsDataViewController.h"

@interface ResultsDataViewController ()
@end

@implementation ResultsDataViewController
@synthesize data;
```

Then I have my UIView with class name Plot.h/m

Plot.h:

```
@interface PlotGraph : UIView <CPTBarPlotDataSource, CPTBarPlotDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* receivedName;
@end
```

Plot.m:

```
#import "Plot.h"
@interface Plot()

@end

@implementation PlotGraph
@synthesize receivedName;
```

...

=====

Question:

HOW do I pass the value of name from my UIViewController and assign it to the variable receivedName in my UIView?

The UIView Plot is a view in my UIViewController DataViewController

Comment: `plotGraph.receivedName = self.name`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Note: `@synthesize data;` in your question is probably a typo.  I'll assume you meant `@synthesize name;`.  Also, `@interface Plot()` should probably be `@interface PlotGraph()`.)

First, you need to have a reference to a `PlotGraph` object either as something you create in code or something that you load into an `IBOutlet` variable from your xib file or storyboard.  Once you have that, either where you create it or in `viewDidLoad:`, it's simply something like:

```
plotView.receivedName = self.name;
```